# Find a formula for the projection onto the unit ball of a Euclidean space

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

> Set $C = \left\{x \in X | \left\|x\right\| \le 1\right\}$. Find a formula for projection of set $C$, i.e., $P_C$, and prove it rigorously.

The norm is Euclidean norm. $X$ can be understood as $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*Progress*: I found the formula $${\left\| {{P_C}\left( x \right)} \right\|^2} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1, & x \in X \setminus C\\ \left\|x\right\|^2, & x \in C \end{array} \right.$$ However, I'm not sure how to prove the projection of $x \in X\setminus C$ is on the surface of a ball, i.e., $x \in C\setminus \rm{ri} C$.

Comment: This is a maths question and moreover it is unclear (what is $X$ ? what is the norm ?).

Comment: The norm is Euclidean norm. $X$ can be understood as $\mathbb{R}^n$. Actually, I found the formula ${\left\| {{P_C}\left( x \right)} \right\|^2} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1, &x \in X \setminus C\\
\left\|x\right\|^2, &x \in C
\end{array} \right..$. However, I'm not sure how to prove the projection of $x \in X\setminus C$ is on the surface of a ball, i.e., $x \in \bar C\setminus C$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the characterization of the projection via a variational inequality?